# How to generate a single pulse signal with existing clock signal

Tags: signal, clock, pulse

There are 2 input signals to the circuit.
one is the clock signal of 1MHZ.
the other one is the 'input'.

Making use the clock signal, how do I generate a single pulse when the input signal changes from low to high, with appropriate circuit.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, let me modify the question

Comment: See: https://vhdlguide.com/2016/07/23/edge-detector/

Comment: What is the technology you're working with? PLC? Discrete logic - if so, what family? PLD? FPGA? Without this important detail, the question is too broad and off-topic here.

Comment: Assuming the clock is faster than input pulse width, It's a simple positive edge detector. You need an AND gate a D flop.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you could **AND** the input signal with the clock signal to get a gated clock signal. Then you could use a negative-edge-triggered, D-type flip-flop clocked from the gated clock signal to detect the first falling edge of the gated clock and clear its \$\overline{Q}\$ output.

The \$\overline{Q}\$ output could then **AND** with the gated clock signal resulting in a single pulse (what you want).

[image]

- OUT1 is the gated clock
- OUT2 is the end-of-first-pulse detector
- OUT3 is, I believe what you might want

But there are other things to consider that you haven't mentioned in your question such as what happens when the input signal goes low again and returns high - maybe you don't want another pulse to be generated or, maybe you do? You need to address this if you want a proper answer.

You also should consider that the input signal might not be synchronous with the clock signal and, the pulse produced could be very thin and cause problems: -

[image]